# Removing child-function event listeners

Tags: javascript, event-handling, listener

In building an extended `input` field (a complex date picker), I need to use two key event listeners. One is attached to the input field, and launches the interface. This is easy.

The second is attached to `document`, in order to close the complex overlay. Click on the overlay, and it does nothing. Click outside: the overlay disappears and the input field's value is updated.

It also needs to remove the event listener from the `document`.

This would all be straightforward… if it weren't based on object structures. I am not calling a stand-alone function. I am calling a child function of the data object associated with the field (which the field then has no way of referencing back to).

```
__DateField.prototype.activate = function () {
…
var t = this;
window.setTimeout(function () { document.addEventListener("click", function (ev) { t.closeDateSelector(ev) }, false); }, 0);
…
}
```

(I haven't figured out why that event attachment needs to be nested within the `setTimeout`, but if I don''t do it that way, it calls itself immediately.)

Anyhow, the problem is then that I cannot successfully call `document.removeEventListener()` because I it's not the same initial function.

Also, I can't approach it by attaching the function as a stand-alone, because I *need* the reference to the related `__DateField` object.

How can I remove that function from `document`?

I have looked at the various threads that say there is no way to inspect event listeners added via 'addEventListener`, though wonder if they may be out of date, as Firebug can list them…

Comment: I suspect it may have something to do with the function that process is embedded within being called from within an added event listener…

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was misremembering the DOM events spec. It says the *propagation path* (the elements on which the event will occurr) must be determined at the outset and not changed, but it doesn't say that the *handlers* must be determined in advance. So within a handler for a bubbling event, adding a handler for that same event to an ancestor element does indeed then cause that handler to get fired. [Example](http://jsbin.com/botaqugezo/1) | [Relevant section of DOM events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) `setTimeout` is the perfect way to address it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove it, you must have a reference to the function, so the question boils down to: How can I keep a reference to the function?

The simplest answer, since you already have an object handy, is a property on the object, if you can rely on `this` being correct as of when you do the removal:

```
__DateField.prototype.activate = function () {
    // …
    var t = this;
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        t.listener = function (ev) {
            t.closeDateSelector(ev)
        };
        document.addEventListener("click", listener, false);
    }, 0);
    // …
};

// To remove
__DateField.prototype.deactivate = function() {
    if (this.listener != null) {
        document.removeEventListener("click", this.listener, false);
        this.listener = null;
    }
};
```

Or if that's a problem for some reason, you could use a variable in a scoping function:

```
(function() {
    var listener = null;

    __DateField.prototype.activate = function () {
        // …
        var t = this;
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            listener = function (ev) {
                t.closeDateSelector(ev)
            };
            document.addEventListener("click", listener, false);
        }, 0);
        // …
    };

    // Later, when removing
    function removeIt() {
        if (listener != null) {
            document.removeEventListener("click", listener, false);
            listener = null;
        }
    }
})();
```